Найти строку в текстовом файле
У меня есть код для вывода из текстового файла в консоль. Нужно найти строку в этом тексте. Пыталась через qFind, но не могу в line добавить весь текст.
Работаю на Qt C++

Читать файл по строкам и искать в каждой строке не пробовали?

По строкам я его вывожу, но как по строкам читать - не знаю

Читать файл по строкам -- man 3 fgets
